# How to find overall significance for main effects in a dummy interaction using anova()

Tags: r, anova, interaction, cox-regression

I run a Cox Regression with two categorical variables (x1 and x2) and their interaction. I need to know the significance of the overall effect of x1, x2 and of the interaction.

**The overall effect of the interaction:**

I know how do find out the overall effect of the interaction using `anova()`:

```
library(survival)
fit_x1_x2 <- coxph(Surv(time, death) ~ x1 + x2        , data= df)
fit_full <-  coxph(Surv(time, death) ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data= df)
anova(fit_x1_x2, fit_full)
```

But how are we supposed to use `anova()` to find out the overall effect of x1 or x2? What I tried is this:

**The overall effect of x1**

```
fit_x2_ia <- coxph(Surv(time, death) ~      x2 + x1:x2, data= df)
fit_full <- coxph(Surv(time, death)  ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data= df)
anova(fit_x2_ia, fit_full)
```

**The overall effect of x2**

```
fit_x1_ia <- coxph(Surv(time, death) ~ x1 +      x1:x2, data= df)
fit_full <- coxph(Surv(time, death)  ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2, data= df)
anova(fit_x1_ia, fit_full)
```

I am not sure whether this is how we are supposed to use `anova()`. The fact that the output shows degree of freedom is zero makes me sceptical. I am even more puzzled that both times, for the overall effect of x1 and x2, the test is significant, although the log likelihood values of the models are the same and the Chi value is zero.

**Here is the data I used**

```
set.seed(1) # make it reproducible
df <- data.frame(x1= rnorm(1000), x2= rnorm(1000)) # generate data         
df$death <- rbinom(1000,1, 1/(1+exp(-(1 + 2 * df$x1 + 3 * df$x2 + df$x1 * df$x2)))) # dead or not
library(tidyverse) # for cut_number() function
df$x1 <- cut_number(df$x1, 4); df$x2 <- cut_number(df$x2, 4) # make predictors to groups
df$time <- rnorm(1000); df$time[df$time<0] <- -df$time[df$time<0] # add survival times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from 42- is informative but after reading it I still did not know how to determine the three p values or if this is possible at all. Thus I talked to the professor of biostatistic of my university. His answer was quite simple and I share it in case others have similar questions.

In this design it is not possible to determine the three p values for overall effect of x1, x2 and their interaction. If we want to know the p values of the three overall effects, we need to keep the continuous variables as they are. But breaking up the variables into groups answers a different question, hence we can not test the hypothesis of the overall effects no matter which statisstical model we use.

Answer (score 1):

The two models you have constructed for  "overall effect" do really not appear to  satisfy the statistical property of being hierarchical, i.e properly nested. Specifically,  if you look at the actual models that get constructed with that code you should see that they are actually the same model with different labels for the two-way crossed effects. In both cases you have 15 estimated coefficients (hence zero degrees of freedom difference) and you will not that the `x1` parameter in the full model has the same coefficient as the `x2[-3.2532,-0.6843):x1[-0.6973,-0.0347)` parameter in the "reduced" model looking for an x1-effect, namely 0.19729. The crossing operator is basically filling in all the missing cells for the main effects with interaction results.

There really is little value in looking at interaction models without all of the main effects if you want to stay within the bounds of generally accepted statistical practice.

If you type:

```
fit_full
```

... you should get a summary of the model that has p-values for x1 levels, x2 levels,and the interaction levels. Because you chose to categorize these by four arbitrary cutpoints each you will end up with a total of 15 parameter estimates. If instead you made no cuts and modeled the linear effects and the linear-by-linear interaction, you could get three p-values directly. I'm guessing there was suspicion that the effects were not linear and if so I thought a cubic spline model might be more parsimonious and distort the biological reality less than discretization into 4 disjoint levels. If you thought the effects might be non-linear but ordinal, there is an ordinal version of factor classed variables, but the results are generally confusion to the uninitiated.

Comment: Related: [Principle of Marginality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality)

Comment: @42 Thank you a lot! So this is not the way to do it as stated in my question Could you please explain how to find out the overall significance for x1 and x2 in the example above? That would be of great help to me.

Comment: @avid_useR That is an interesting ressource. It says that "In the case of interaction, it is wrong to try to test, estimate, or interpret a "main effect" coefficient b or c, omitting the interaction term.". That makes sense to me. Anyway, my goal is not to test the main effects separately (which is obviously not recommended). I am rather wondering how to correctly test the significance of the overall main effect of x1 and x2 (considering that they interact). In case of continuous variables, this is easily done. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Overall effect of both X1 and X2 would be tested by comparing the null model `Surv(time, death) ~ 1` to the model with x1,x2 and the interaction (the full model you are now using. I would advise using a cubic spline model for both terms and their interaction, since it would be more general and have fewer degrees of freedom.

Comment: @42 If it was up to me I would not break up the variables in the first place since this has bad [consequences](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous). But I am supposed to do it like this. Further, I am supposed to report the overall significance of the three effects (x1, x2 and the interaction). But if I understand it right, this is not possible in this situation.

Comment: I think thge "overall effect of the two variable and the interaction" is tested in the full model versus the null model. I think the spline model with interaction would be a more powerful test and probably more accurate than the two way 4 level cuts of continuous variables that were used, but who am I to argue with your boss. He is undoubtedly a PhD in statistics, right?

Comment: @42 "I think thge "overall effect of the two variable and the interaction". Yes, that is right. But I need to report *three* p values for the *three* overall effects of x1, x2 and the interaction. No, unfortunately my boss is not a statician but has a background in medicine. I agree with you that there are superior approaches like splines. I am surprised that there is no way to get the p values for the three overall effects in such a seemingly simple situation and well, it's going to be hard to explain to my boss.

Comment: I also have a background in medicine (MD as well as a Masters in Public Health), and can tell you that most physicians know precious little statistics. I posted some further comments above as to options. The strategy of cutting continuous variables into discrete levels (which is at the heart of your difficulties)  is a typical strategy of physicians when they lay out analysis plans, but is generally doing violence to the data and failing to make optimal use for statistical inference.